# bulma calendar to show only month option

Tags: html, css, bulma

Is it possible to give only MM/YYYY option in bulma-calendar extension ? The default option shows dd-mm-yyyy?

```
<div class ="date-cal">
    <input type = "date">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the type "month" for input tags in HTML:

```html
<input type="month" min="2018-03" value="2018-05">
```